# Hough Transform C# code

Tags: c#, image-processing, hough-transform

Let us take a look at  [this C# implementation](https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/a9453dad025d1fbffab165293cedc976187da535/Sources/Imaging/HoughLineTransformation.cs#L457),

```
        ... ...

        // get source image size
        int width       = image.Width;
        int height      = image.Height;
        int halfWidth   = width / 2;
        int halfHeight  = height / 2;

        // make sure the specified rectangle recides with the source image
        rect.Intersect( new Rectangle( 0, 0, width, height ) );

        int startX = -halfWidth  + rect.Left;
        int startY = -halfHeight + rect.Top;
        int stopX  = width  - halfWidth  - ( width  - rect.Right );
        int stopY  = height - halfHeight - ( height - rect.Bottom );

        int offset = image.Stride - rect.Width;

        // calculate Hough map's width
        int halfHoughWidth = (int) Math.Sqrt( halfWidth * halfWidth + halfHeight * halfHeight );
        int houghWidth = halfHoughWidth * 2;

        houghMap = new short[houghHeight, houghWidth];

        // do the job
        unsafe
        {
            byte* src = (byte*) image.ImageData.ToPointer( ) +
                rect.Top * image.Stride + rect.Left;

            // for each row
            for ( int y = startY; y < stopY; y++ )
            {
                // for each pixel
                for ( int x = startX; x < stopX; x++, src++ )
                {
                    if ( *src != 0 )
                    {
                        // for each Theta value
                        for ( int theta = 0; theta < houghHeight; theta++ )
                        {
                            int radius = (int) Math.Round( cosMap[theta] * x - sinMap[theta] * y ) + halfHoughWidth;

                            if ( ( radius < 0 ) || ( radius >= houghWidth ) )
                                continue;

                            houghMap[theta, radius]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                src += offset;
            }
        }

        ... ... ...
```

**Q.1.** *`rect.Intersect(new Rectangle( 0, 0, width, height));` - why is this line important?*

**Q.2.** *Why are values modified using `rect` In the following code:*

```
int startX = -halfWidth  + rect.Left;
int startY = -halfHeight + rect.Top;
int stopX  = width  - halfWidth  - ( width  - rect.Right );
int stopY  = height - halfHeight - ( height - rect.Bottom );
```

**Q.3.** *Why are the y, and x loops starting in a negative point?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Q.1.

This line simply ensures that the bounding rectangle is completely inside the image. If you were to skip this, and `rect` is (partly) outside the image, you'd end up indexing out of bounds.

Note that pixel access is done through a pointer, incrementing the pointer by 1 for every x-increment, and by `offset` for every y-increment. If `rect` is larger than the image, we'd increment the pointer past the image buffer. If `rect` is simply shifted out the image bounds, but not too large, we'd read pixels that do not correspond to the coordinates we're using.

## Q.2.

Note that

```
int stopX  = width  - halfWidth  - ( width  - rect.Right );
int stopY  = height - halfHeight - ( height - rect.Bottom );
```

can be simplified to

```
int stopX  = - halfWidth  + rect.Right;
int stopY  = - halfHeight + rect.Bottom;
```

The code defines the origin of the coordinate system in the middle of the image. This bit of code shifts the bounding box (originally defined in the range [0,`width`) and [0,`height`) ) to the new coordinate system.

Usually the Hough transform is defined with the origin in the top-left pixel. But in principle it does not matter how the coordinate system is defined, this just modifies the parametrization of a line. The sinusoid drawn for each input pixel will be different, but the local maxima will still appear for the set of parameters corresponding to lines in the image.

Comment: Regarding the original Q.3: the C++ code doesn't need to test `radius` because there the parameter space (`_accu`) is defined such that any radius you can define within the image will be within the valid range.