# Hough Line Transform implementation

Tags: c#, hough-transform

I am trying to implement [Hough Line Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Implementation).

**Input.** I am using the following image as input. This single line is expected to produce only one intersection of sine waves in the output.

[image]

**Desired behavior.** my source code is expected to produce the following output as it was generated by the [sample application](https://github.com/mdavid/aforge.net/tree/master/Samples/Imaging/HoughTransformation) of AForge framework.

[image]

Here, we can see:

1. the dimension of the output is identical to the input image.
2. the intersection of sine waves are seen at almost at the center.
3. the intersection pattern of waves is very small and simple.

**Present behavior.** My source code is producing the following output which is different than that of the output generated by AForge.

[image]

- the intersection is not at the center.
- the wave patterns are also different.

**Why is my code producing a different output?**

.

***Source Code***

I have written the following code myself. The following is [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) source code.

```
public class HoughMap
{
    public int[,] houghMap { get; private set; }
    public int[,] image { get; set; }

    public void Compute()
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            // get source image size
            int inWidth = image.GetLength(0);
            int inHeight = image.GetLength(1);

            int inWidthHalf = inWidth / 2;
            int inHeightHalf = inHeight / 2;

            int outWidth = (int)Math.Sqrt(inWidth * inWidth + inHeight * inHeight);
            int outHeight = 180;
            int outHeightHalf = outHeight / 2;

            houghMap = new int[outWidth, outHeight];

            // scanning through each (x,y) pixel of the image--+
            for (int y = 0; y < inHeight; y++)               //|
            {                                                //|
                for (int x = 0; x < inWidth; x++)//<-----------+
                {
                    if (image[x, y] != 0)//if a pixel is black, skip it.
                    {
                        // We are drawing some Sine waves. So, it may 
                        // vary from -90 to +90 degrees.
                        for (int theta = -outHeightHalf; theta < outHeightHalf; theta++)
                        {
                            double rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;
                            // respective radius value is computed
                            //int radius = (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(rad) * (x - inWidthHalf) - Math.Sin(rad) * (y - inHeightHalf));
                            //int radius = (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(rad) * (x + inWidthHalf) - Math.Sin(rad) * (y + inHeightHalf));
                            int radius = (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(rad) * (x) - Math.Sin(rad) * (outHeight - y));

                            // if the radious value is between 1 and 
                            if ((radius > 0) && (radius <= outWidth))
                            {
                                houghMap[radius, theta + outHeightHalf]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap;

        int[,] intImage = ToInteger(bitmap);

        HoughMap houghMap = new HoughMap();
        houghMap.image = intImage;
        houghMap.Compute();

        int[,] normalized = Rescale(houghMap.houghMap);

        Bitmap hough = ToBitmap(normalized, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        pictureBox2.Image = hough;
    }

    public static int[,] Rescale(int[,] image)
    {
        int[,] imageCopy = (int[,])image.Clone();

        int Width = imageCopy.GetLength(0);
        int Height = imageCopy.GetLength(1);

        int minVal = 0;
        int maxVal = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
            {
                double conv = imageCopy[i, j];

                minVal = (int)Math.Min(minVal, conv);
                maxVal = (int)Math.Max(maxVal, conv);
            }
        }

        int minRange = 0;
        int maxRange = 255;

        int[,] array2d = new int[Width, Height];

        for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
            {
                array2d[i, j] = (maxRange - minRange) * (imageCopy[i,j] - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal) + minRange;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }

    public int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap input)
    {
        int Width = input.Width;
        int Height = input.Height;

        int[,] array2d = new int[Width, Height];

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                Color cl = input.GetPixel(x, y);

                int gray = (int)Convert.ChangeType(cl.R * 0.3 + cl.G * 0.59 + cl.B * 0.11, typeof(int));

                array2d[x, y] = gray;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }

    public Bitmap ToBitmap(int[,] image, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        int[,] imageCopy = (int[,])image.Clone();

        int Width = imageCopy.GetLength(0);
        int Height = imageCopy.GetLength(1);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, pixelFormat);

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                int iii = imageCopy[x, y];

                Color clr = Color.FromArgb(iii, iii, iii);

                bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: take a look at this library https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/a5f0ae95c2c7b7996ad0c5403a2953dfa3c1d8fd/Samples/Imaging/Hough%20Transform/MainForm.cs#L35

Comment: Without any link to the specific algorithm you are using and a [mcve] with 1) compilable code, 2) the *simplest possible image* for which a wrong result is returned, this is likely to get closed as too broad or off-topic for stack overflow.  I notice you also asked [Hough Transform C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51863258).  Are you asking us to explain why this code returns a different result than that code?

Comment: Apparently, you have no statistical analysis in place that can determine the line placement. A common method is implementing a form of Gaussian Kernel that can model the "uncertain space" (something like an edge detection), otherwise your votes will go all over the place. See [this simple description](https://shapeofdata.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/gaussian-kernels/).

Comment: The C++ code is using OpenCV. Another perspective, probably. It looks like you're happy with your code now, but I think you still have work to do. You are moving the space, defining your target as ortocentric. Is it the expected scenario? (I also think it's pretty clear what you're trying to accomplish and this doesn't deserve downvotes, in my presonal view).

Comment: @Jimi, `The C++ code is using OpenCV.` --- not true.

Comment: Yes, it is. You forgot to look at `main.cpp`, where you'll find `#include "hough.h"` and then in `void doTransform()` you'll see `hough.Transform(img_edge.data, w, h);` where `img_edge.data` is the edge detection data coming from `cv::Canny(img_blur, img_edge, 100, 150, 3);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem from [this link](https://github.com/davidchatting/hough_lines/blob/master/HoughTransform.java). The source code from this link is the best one I have ever came across.

[image]

```
public class HoughMap
{
    public int[,] houghMap { get; private set; }
    public int[,] image { get; set; }

    public void Compute()
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            // get source image size
            int Width = image.GetLength(0);
            int Height = image.GetLength(1);

            int centerX = Width / 2;
            int centerY = Height / 2;

            int maxTheta = 180;
            int houghHeight = (int)(Math.Sqrt(2) * Math.Max(Width, Height)) / 2;
            int doubleHeight = houghHeight * 2;
            int houghHeightHalf = houghHeight / 2;
            int houghWidthHalf = maxTheta / 2;

            houghMap = new int[doubleHeight, maxTheta];

            // scanning through each (x,y) pixel of the image--+
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)                 //|
            {                                                //|
                for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)//<-------------+
                {
                    if (image[x, y] != 0)//if a pixel is black, skip it.
                    {
                        // We are drawing some Sine waves.  
                        // It may vary from -90 to +90 degrees.
                        for (int theta = 0; theta < maxTheta; theta++)
                        {
                            double rad = theta *Math.PI / 180;
                            // respective radius value is computed
                            int rho = (int)(((x - centerX) * Math.Cos(rad)) + ((y - centerY) * Math.Sin(rad)));

                            // get rid of negative value
                            rho += houghHeight;

                            // if the radious value is between 
                            // 1 and twice the houghHeight 
                            if ((rho > 0) && (rho <= doubleHeight))
                            {
                                houghMap[rho, theta]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just look at [this C++ code](https://github.com/brunokeymolen/hough/blob/master/hough.cpp), and [this C# code](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Imaging/HoughLineTransformation.cs). So, complicated and messy that my brain got arrested. Especially, the C++ one. I never anticipated someone to store 2D values in a 1D array.