# Hough Peak detection

Tags: c#, image-processing, hough-transform

I have implemented Hough Peak Detection. The output is as follows:

[image]

We can see that the RED line intersects the both (left, right) sides of the canvas.

**How can I limit the detected line between the length of the source line?**

For instance,

[image]

.

*Source Code*

```
public class Line
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
}

public class HoughLineTransform
{
    public HoughMap Accumulator { get; set; }

    public HoughLineTransform()
    {
    }

    public List<Line> GetLines(int threshold)
    {
        if (Accumulator == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("HoughMap is null");
        }

        int houghWidth = Accumulator.Width;
        int houghHeight = Accumulator.Height;
        int imageWidth = Accumulator.Image.Width;
        int imageHeight = Accumulator.Image.Height;

        List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

        if (Accumulator == null)
            return lines;

        for (int rho = 0; rho < houghWidth; rho++)
        {
            for (int theta = 0; theta < houghHeight; theta++)
            {
                if ((int)Accumulator[rho, theta] >= threshold)
                {
                    int peak = Accumulator[rho, theta];

                    for (int ly = -4; ly <= 4; ly++)
                    {
                        for (int lx = -4; lx <= 4; lx++)
                        {
                            if ((ly + rho >= 0 && ly + rho < houghWidth) && (lx + theta >= 0 && lx + theta < houghHeight))
                            {
                                if ((int)Accumulator[rho + ly, theta + lx] > peak)
                                {
                                    peak = Accumulator[rho + ly, theta + lx];
                                    ly = lx = 5;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (peak > (int)Accumulator[rho, theta])
                        continue;

                    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
                    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;

                    double rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;

                    if (theta >= 45 && theta <= 135)
                    {
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((x1 - (imageWidth / 2)) * Math.Cos(rad))) / Math.Sin(rad) + (imageHeight / 2));
                        x2 = imageWidth - 0;
                        y2 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((x2 - (imageWidth / 2)) * Math.Cos(rad))) / Math.Sin(rad) + (imageHeight / 2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        y1 = 0;
                        x1 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((y1 - (imageHeight / 2)) * Math.Sin(rad))) / Math.Cos(rad) + (imageWidth / 2));
                        y2 = imageHeight - 0;
                        x2 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((y2 - (imageHeight / 2)) * Math.Sin(rad))) / Math.Cos(rad) + (imageWidth / 2));
                    }

                    lines.Add(new Line(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2)));
                }
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }
}
```

> <sup>Related: [*Hough Line Transform implementation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51882150/159072)</sup>

Comment: Due to the nature of HT it will give you a peak for a line there is no segment information. (For example: you would have a similar HT map for dashed lines). Now if you want to detect the segment you could try scanning the proximity (depending on the HT resolution) of the line and decide where the (majority) of the points are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to overlay the resulting houghlines on the original image and check where the pixels overlap (with a certain window).

If they start or end overlapping, you have the start / end of your line segment.

By the way: I have not checked your algorithm, but I wrote one myself some 15 years ago. I remember having an iterative approach, where you find one line at the time (just the max in the accumulated image). 
After a line is found, remove the accumulated pixels for that line and you start again by finding the max. 
You then find the second-most-important line. And so on.