# Hough transform for finding straight lines

Tags: c#

I need to write a Hough transform to find straight lines. I convert the original image to monochrome in advance. First, I walk through the entire image and build a Hough space.

```
public void Hough(Bitmap bitmap, int[,] Hough, int maxLength)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
                {
                    for (int tetha = 0; tetha < 360; tetha++)
                    {
                        int ro = (int)(x * Math.Cos(tetha) + y * Math.Sin(tetha));
                        Hough[Math.Abs(ro), tetha]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, I walk through the resulting two-dimensional array and look for the ro and tetha indexes of the maximum value in the array.

```
 int max = int.MinValue;
        int roCount = 0; int tethaCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
            {
                if (Hough[i, j] >= max)
                {
                    max = Hough[i, j];
                    roCount = i;
                    tethaCount = j;
                }
            }
       }
```

Next, I need to find the line on the source image using the found indexes. But how do I do this? I sit for 5 hours and don't understand anything

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming challenge. It sounds more like a mathematics issue.

Comment: THere seem to be quite a few existing questions re the Hough Transform on SO already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hough-transform+c%23

Comment: The question might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886680/hough-peak-detection